# How to reset password for Chef web server without email

Tags: chef, chef-server

I'm running a Chef server in the cloud. I can't log into the "Chef Manage" web interface because I forgot my password.

I can still use knife to (for example) update nodes from my workstation using the server.

I can still ssh to the server using my private key. I tried running `sudo private-chef-ctl password myusername` and "successfully" changed my password; however, when I try to sign in using the new password, the web interface still says "*Maximum login failures reached, please reset your password.*"

When I submit the password reset form in the web interface, it says "*Your password reset email has been sent*", but my server isn't configured to send emails.

How can I reset my password so that I can log into the Chef server using the web interface?

Answer (score 5):

Run the following command:

```
$ chef-server-ctl password "USERNAME"
NewPassword
ReEnter
```

Important: To reset Web UI, run: `chef-manage-ctl restart`

Answer (score 0):

Chef Manage is a premium feature supported by Chef Software. You can reach their support team at support@chef.io.

Chances are the CLI tools aren't set up to reset the failed login counters as generally you either use all the web tools or none of them (in which case you don't need to deal with passwords at all).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Linux box, you can change your email address to `<user>@<hostname>` using `chef-server-ctl user-edit <chef_username>` command. You can check the email via the `mail` command.

A more elegant solution would be to install a smtp proxy in the same box.